# how to enable the shortest match rule in flex (lexer)?

Tags: match, flex-lexer, shortest

By default flex uses the longest match rule. 
Is there any way to override this behavior to make it match the shortest sequence?

Thank you

Comment: No, and you wouldn't want it if you had it. For example, many if not most lexers (certainly all mine) end with a catch-all rule `. return yytext[0];`. That would become the only rule that did anything.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Why-doesn_0027t-flex-have-non_002dgreedy-operators-like-perl-does_003f.html) in the Flex manual says that it doesn't have any non-greedy operators because it is a scanner rather than a parser, and suggests regular expressions could be used to add the missing functionality.

Comment: i didn't mean the greedy operators per se.If you have completely separate regexprs both matching the same prefix of some string a lexer by default chooses the longest one. what i need is to make it pick up the shorter one, reset, and start matching again.